# Impossible to use functions from another file in OCAML

Tags: function, compilation, ocaml

First of all i use the following makefile to compile (i don't know if it's important, but since i compile with it...):

```
NAME =  project


ML =    project.ml \
        main.ml


MLI =   project.mli


CMI = $(MLI:.mli=.cmi)
CMO = $(ML:.ml=.cmo)
CMX = $(ML:.ml=.cmx)


OCAMLDPE = ocamldep
CAMLFLAGS = -w Aelz -warn-error A
OCAMLC = ocamlc $(CAMLFLAGS)
OCAMLOPT = ocamlopt $(CAMLFLAGS)
OCAMLDOC = ocamldoc -html -d $(ROOT)/doc


all:        .depend $(CMI) $(NAME)

byte:       .depend $(CMI) $(NAME).byte


$(NAME):    $(CMX)
        @$(OCAMLOPT) -o $@ str.cmxa $(CMX)
        @echo "[OK] $(NAME) linked"

$(NAME).byte:   $(CMO)
        @$(OCAMLC) -o $@ str.cma $(CMO)
        @echo "[OK] $(NAME).byte linked"

%.cmx:      %.ml
        @$(OCAMLOPT) -c $<
        @echo "[OK] [$<] builded"

%.cmo:      %.ml
        @$(OCAMLC) -c $<
        @echo "[OK] [$<] builded"

%.cmi:      %.mli
        @$(OCAMLC) -c $<
        @echo "[OK] [$<] builded"

documentation:  $(CMI)
        @$(OCAMLDOC) $(MLI)
        @echo "[OK] Documentation"


re:     fclean all


clean:
        @/bin/rm -f *.cm* *.o .depend *~
        @echo "[OK] clean"


fclean:     clean
        @/bin/rm -f $(NAME) $(NAME).byte
        @echo "[OK] fclean"


.depend:
        @/bin/rm -f .depend
        @$(OCAMLDPE) $(MLI) $(ML) > .depend
        @echo "[OK] dependencies"
```

I've 3 files, my `main.ml`, a `project.ml` and a `project.mli`
i've a simple function yolo in the `main.ml` :

```
let yolo lol = 
    print_string(lol)
;;
```

But when i try to call it in my `project.ml` like that:

```
Main.yolo "lol";
```

I just have an error, saying that the module `Main` is not bound:

```
[OK] [project.mli] builded
File "project.ml", line 34, characters 1-10:
Error: Unbound module Main
make: *** [project.cmx] Erreur 2
```

also here is the content of `project.ml` (`project.mli` is empty) :

```
let rec project l =
    Main.yolo l;
;;

Random.self_init ();;

let _ = project [] ;;
```

While searching on the stackoverflow's already asked question i've found tons of peoples having the same issue.... because they was using `#use`, but it's not my case.

As a beginner, if you could explain me it would be awesome :).

Comment: It would be helpful to have the contents of `main.ml`, `project.ml`, `project.mli`, and the exact error message. Also when does this error message happen? when a module is built or during the linking phase?

Comment: @ÉtienneMillon added :) there is nothing incredible, hope it can help anyway ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Makefile, the `ML` list of modules should be sorted in a topological order, i.e., a module should be specified after all its dependencies. In your case the header of your Makefile should look like this:

```
NAME =  project

ML =    main.ml \
        project.ml
```

Last but not least, I strongly recommend you not to use Makefiles to compile OCaml programs unless you really know what you're doing and how low-level OCaml toolchain operates. Use `ocamlbuild` for small projects, and `oasis` for the large one. In your case, you don't need anything specific to build your project, just do

```
ocamlbuild project.native
```

And you will get the binary. It will also keep you working directory clean (and if it is dirty already, it will help you to sanitize it).

Answer (score 2):

You have code to compute the dependencies but you do not include them. So `Project` is built when `Main` is not built yet.

Adding the following line at the end of your `Makefile` fixes it:

```
-include .depend
```

That being said, I would advise against using `make` and use a build tool like `ocamlbuild`. Without any setup you can run `ocamlbuild project.byte` and have equivalent functionality.

Comment: This will only defer the error to the linking phase. You still need to specify the modules in the topological order as the linking rule depends explicitly on the CMO list that is built from the ML list.